# How Do I Get the Best Parameters for each DF in a Dictionary of DFs Using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

One, I have a dictionary of dataframes, dfs, with five different dataframes in it.

Two, I am using a scikit-learn regressor, RandomForest with the following parameters:

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = None)

num_estimators = list(np.linspace(10, 100, num=5, endpoint=True).astype(int))
max_features = ["auto", "sqrt", "log2"]
min_samples_split = [2,4,8]

params = {'regressor__n_estimators': num_estimators,
          'regressor__max_features': max_features,
          'regressor__min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
          'regressor__bootstrap': [False]},
```

Three the elements of my pipeline are as below:

```
# numeric columns to use
num_columns = list(subset_features[2:])

# pipeline for processing numerical feeatures
num_transformer = Pipeline([('impute', IterativeImputer()),
                            ('scale', StandardScaler())])

column_transformer = ColumnTransformer([('num_pipeline', num_transformer, num_columns)])


# the pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("ct", column_transformer), ("reg", regressor)])
```

Finally, the gridsearch and fit are the following:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                  param_grid=params, 
                  cv=5, 
                  n_jobs=-1,
                  verbose=1, 
                  scoring=scorer # a user-defined scoring function,
                  refit=True)

# run the gs for each dataframe
gs_output = {}
for id, df in enumerate(dfs.values()):
    print('starting id:', id)
    gs_results[id] = gs.fit(df)
```

Afer running the above model, my attempts at getting the best parameters for each dataframe with `gs.best_params_`
retrieves only one set of best parameters, shown below.

```
Best params: {'bootstrap': False, 'max_features': 'log2', 'min_samples_split': 4, 'n_estimators': 10}
```

What I want is to get five best parameter estimates, one for each dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I think I came up with a solution that does what I wanted to do. I simply had to wrap the code in a function and output a tuple of output of what I wanted to see and iterate over function. Below is my updated code.

```
def GridSearchCVRF(x, y):

    # the estimator and parameters
    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = None)

    num_estimators = list(np.linspace(10, 100, num=5, endpoint=True).astype(int))
    max_features = ["auto", "sqrt", "log2"]
    min_samples_split = [2,4,8]

    params = {'regressor__n_estimators': num_estimators,
              'regressor__max_features': max_features,
              'regressor__min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
              'regressor__bootstrap': [False]},
    
    # numeric columns to use
    num_columns = list(subset_features[2:])

    # pipeline for processing numerical feeatures
    num_transformer = Pipeline([('impute', IterativeImputer()),
                                ('scale', StandardScaler())])
    column_transformer = ColumnTransformer([('num_pipeline', num_transformer, num_columns)])


    # the pipeline
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("ct", column_transformer), ("reg", regressor)])

    # the gridsearch and fit the following:
    gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                      param_grid=params, 
                      cv=5, 
                      n_jobs=-1,
                      verbose=1, 
                      scoring=scorer # a user-defined scoring function,
                      refit=True)

    gs.fit(x, y)
    return gs.best_score, gs.best_params
```

I then ran the following code on the function and got the outputs: `best scores` and `best params` for each dataframe used in the random forest model.

```
# fit the model function
best_scores = {}
best_params = {}
for i, df in enumerate(dfs.values()):
    print('starting i...:', i)
    best_scores[i], best_params[i] = GridSearchCVRF(df)
print('best scores', best_scores[i])
print('best params', best_params[i])
```